# Inserir valores em lista

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um exercício de Python que pede para o usuário colocar cinco números de 1 a 5, se o usuário digitar um numero que não atenda esse critério retorne um erro e não inclua o nº na lista
fiz dessa forma:

```
lista = int(input("digite um numero de 1 a 5"))

if lista > 1  and  lista < 5:   
    print("Excelente")
else:
    print("numero invalido")

print(lista)
```

mas não sei se está certo, pois o correto seria incluir uma lista entre colchetes

como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de instanciar uma lista e inserir elementos nesta lista, seria utilizando o comando condicional `while`.

Para criar um fluxo em que o usuário fique "preso" em um laço até que ele insira 5 elementos e esses mesmos elementos estejam dentro do intervalo de 1 a 5. Seria uma lógica bem parecida com a que já implementou, porém seria necessário algumas coisas a mais.

A lógica, descrita em linguagem natural seria:

1. criar uma lista vazia
2. verificar o tamanho da lista, caso a lista possua o tamanho menor que 5, faça
3. ler um número fornecido pelo usuário
4. verificar se o número fornecidos está no intervalo desejado [1:5], caso façam parte do intervalo adicionar na lista senão perguntar novamente
5. repetir passo 2, 3 e 4.

Acima descrevemos o algoritmo que queremos implementar, a partir desta lógica basta agora transformar essas informações em código Python, uma das perguntas que pode surgir ao implementar é porque utilizar o `while`? O motivo é que teremos um número indeterminado de repetições a fazer, desta forma é recomendado usar o `while`. Este número é indeterminado pois será no mínimo cinco repetições (supondo que os números digitados estejam todos dentro do intervalo e o que ao preencher não haja erros). O usuário será obrigado a preencher os números até que o tamanho da lista seja 5. Mas não temos garantia de quantas vezes o laço será repetido. Isso justifica o uso do `while`.

```
lista = []

while len(lista) < 5:
    n = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    if 1 <= n <= 5:
        lista.append(n)
print(lista)
```

Verifique que assim seria uma implementação simples, existem alguns problemas em relação à tratamento de erro. Para tratar os erros devemos utilizar um bloco `try ... except` para evitar que o nosso programa pare a execução ao encontrar o primeiro erro.

Outro ponto é a escrita do condicional, em Python é possível escrever o condicional desta maneira:

```
if 1 < n < 5: # <-- Veja como estamos comparando a igualdade
```

Porém isso só funciona em Python, então o melhor seria utilizar como você fez, que é uma abordagem mais universal usada em todas as linguagens de programação:

```
if n > 1  and  n < 5:
```

Assim uma implementação mais robusta seria:

```
lista = []

while len(lista) < 5:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite um número: '))
        if 1 <= n <= 5:
            lista.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        print('Número inválido, tente novamente')
    
print(lista)
```

Aprenda mais sobre as funções utilizadas neste código.
[`Função len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), [`bloco try..except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), [comando `while`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=while#ast.While)

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar aqui, mas seria uma coisa mais simples a principio, mas essa solução foi legal